# I found a curious pattern... any idea of a deductive formula? - [4, 24, 80, 200, 420, 784, 1344]

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I found this pattern by taking the absolute value of the difference of both sides of the Cauchy-Schwarz formula with consecutive numbers (I can go into more detail if desired). No worries if this doesn't make sense to you.

I'm looking to find a deductive sequence for this formula (I'm alright if you are able to find a recursive formula too). I can also use a program to generate many more terms of the sequence if you want me to.

Based on intuition, I have a feeling that the answer is going to be a ratio of various factorials.

Let me know if you have any questions... thanks!

Comment: Could you include more details about how you generated those numbers?

Comment: Or could you include more *numbers* in the sequence?

Comment: check out oeis.org, the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: OEIS returns [one result](http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C24%2C80%2C200%2C420%2C784%2C1344&language=english&go=Search).

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like being :
$$
a_n = \frac{(n+1)^2((n+1)^2-1)}{3} = \frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{3}$$

starting with $a_1 = 4$.

EDIT : As Gottfried points out below, it is easier to "shift the index" and go with the formula $a_n = \frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{3}$ with $a_2 = 4$ and $a_1 = 0$.

For example : $a_3= \frac{16 \times 15}{3} = \frac{240}{3} = 80$.

Note that you have missed out the term for $n=5$ which is $420$, but all other terms seem to match.

---

EDIT : Assuming that you have the $420$ in place, so have sufficiently many terms of the sequence to consider, you can use the method of finite differences to check if the terms are polynomial in the index or not.

That is, for a sequence $a_n$ we have the sequence of differences $(\Delta \{a_n\})_k = a_{k+1} - a_k$. Now, if it turns out that $\Delta^t \{a_n\}$ is identically zero, then $a_n$ is in fact a polynomial in $n$ of degree less than $t$.

Once you see this, you can use any $t$ terms of the sequence and try to fit in the coefficients corresponding to the polynomial $a_n  = c_0 + c_1n + ... + c_tn^{t-1}$ to get the coefficients.

---

For example, considering the sequence of finite differences, we get :
\begin{align}
4 & & 24 & & 80 & & 200 & & 420 & & 784 \\
&\quad \quad 20 & & \quad \quad 56 & & \quad \quad 120 & & \quad \quad 220 & & \quad \quad 364 &  \\
& & 36 & & 64 & & 100 & & 144 && \\
& & & \quad \quad 28 & & \quad \quad \ 36 & & \quad \quad \ 44 &&& \\
& & & & 8 & & 8 & & \\
&&&&&\quad \quad \ \ 0&&&&& 
\end{align}
(note : using $1344$ as well one sees that the fifth row gives a sequence of $0$s)

Thus $a_n$ is a quartic in $n$ , and one can use the first four values of the sequence to get the correct expression.

(Alternately, observe that you can hazard a guess at the third row above , which is just the even squares. From there, you can invert the difference operator twice to get the answer).

I have also explained a similar phenomena for powers in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898825/is-this-a-new-method-for-finding-powers/1898835#1898835) answer, where I showed how one can find powers of numbers by inverting the difference technique.

Comment: you're right, i meant to put 420 into there. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewWinter Either way it seems we have got the right sequence!

Comment: Did you put your fingertips on the terminal and mind-meld with the OP to solve this one?  Are you from the planet Vulcan?

Comment: @user2661923 I put my fingertips on the laptop and typed "oeis.org", which threw up no results, but when I truncated to the first four terms this sequence came up. So I was able to answer the question without really ascertaining the context (Cauchy-Schwarz formula etc.) and if that is mind-melding or proof of being from Vulcan, then I am happy I can produce such evidence from the comfort of my office (not the one on planet Vulcan).

Comment: the method of finite differences quickly shows that this (including 420) is a quartic in the indexing variable. The second differences are actually squares, the third differences are linear, the fourth are constant. The constant being 8, we get that the coefficient of $n^4$ must give $24 a_4 = 8$ so it is 1/3

Comment: @WillJagy Good point, I will edit the question.

Comment: to show more terms, I place a second copy of something oversize with a prefix, the ones I remember are \small and \tiny. \huge
\small
\scriptsize
\tiny

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you, I am satisfied with the current output.

Comment: `\Huge 2 \huge 2 \Large 2 \large 2  \small 2 \scriptsize 2 \Tiny 2 \tiny 2`  $ \Huge 2 \huge 2 \Large 2 \large 2  \small 2 \scriptsize 2 \Tiny 2 \tiny 2 $

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The problem is, I use $&$s to delimit the regions, so the pyramid comes right. This does not change the situation, so should I use manual "\quad"s to do it?

Comment: Teresa - well, I have as well no good solution for those triangular tables. I think your array with double `&` is the quickest/simplest one. If it really becomes difficult I printout the table with monospace-font by some wordprocessor and present it "as code" (no mathjax) in the MSE-Q&A-boxes.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thank you for the input. I attempted some changes but failed, so reverted to the usual.

Comment: Just playing around: if the first index $n$ is assumed to be $2$, then $a_n=n^2(n^2-1)/3$. (This is the same as your formula, simply the index moved on step upwards. Perhaps this a bit simpler expression triggered the intuition of the OP towards their guess).

Comment: @GottfriedHelms True, that. I should mention that.